# Is it possible to use `renewcommand` to replace the `hyperref` command with `hyperlink`?

Tags: macros, hyperref

I am using Beamer with Hyperref, and I have a problem with the `\hyperref` command. The link is active, but it sends me to the first slide of the talk. I've read [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) in the Troubleshooting section (bottom of the page) that using `hyperlink` might help. I've tried it and it seems to work.

The problem is that the LaTex file is generated automatically, and I want to replace each occurence of `hyperref` with `hyperlink`. I have tried [renewcommand](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros), but I keep failing.

Is it possible to use `renewcommand` to switch from `hyperref` command to `hyperlink`?

Comment: It sounds to me like you would be better off using an external script (`sed` or `perl`) to convert the file.

Comment: Maybe something like: `sed -i.bak "s/\\hyperref\[(.*)\]/\\hyperlink{\1}/g" infile.tex` (where `infile.tex` is the name of the file you want to edit). The `-i.bak` will save a backup of the original file as `infile.tex.bak`.

Comment: How many times are you compiling? You must compile at least twice, possibly three times or more, to resolve the references. Linking to the first page happens when the target is not defined and that is most probably due to not re-compiling.

Comment: @jon: I've tried using sed regex groups, but I keep getting `invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS` ...

Comment: @cfr: I just tried compiling it five times and the problem is still there, the link points to the first slide.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses `\(` and `\)` rather than `(` and `)`. At least, if this is GNU-type `sed` at the command line. (Editors and other versions use slightly different syntax.)

Comment: Oops. @cfr is right. Try: `sed -i.bak "s/\\hyperref\[\(.*\)\]/\\hyperlink{\1}/g" infile.tex`.